# How do I make an implementation of List.allPairs with List.map?

Tags: list, f#

So far, I've made a function which matches all elements of one list with only the first element of another list, but I need it to match all elements of list 1 with all elements of list 2.

My code so far looks like this:

```
let prototype (lst1: 'a list) (lst2: 'b list) =
    List.map (fun i -> [i,lst2.Head]) lst1 |> List.concat
```

Answer (score 2):

So you figured out how to pair all elements of `lst1` with a single thing. Great!

Now look: inside the `map`'s parameter, you have the exact same problem - pair every element of `lst2` with `i`. So you can just solve it the exact same way:

```
let prototype (lst1: 'a list) (lst2: 'b list) =
    List.map (fun i -> List.map (fun j -> [i, j]) lst2 |> List.concat) lst1 |> List.concat
```

But this is a bit ugly of course. There are a few minor modifications you can make to make it prettier.

First, note that `List.map >> List.concat` is equivalent to `List.collect`:

```
let prototype (lst1: 'a list) (lst2: 'b list) =
    List.collect (fun i -> List.collect (fun j -> [i, j]) lst2) lst1
```

But of course a much better option is to use list comprehensions:

```
let prototype (lst1: 'a list) (lst2: 'b list) =
  [ for i in lst1 do 
      for j in lst2 ->
        i, j
  ]
```